# How to port `__slots__` from Python 2 to 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sed, slots, python-2to3

I have to port a legacy code ( ~60K LOC) from Python 2 to 3 which has a couple of thousand of structures like below:

```
class Sample(object):
    __slots__ = ('both', 'advertise')
    class __metaclass__(type):
        __instancecheck__ = classmethod(
                lambda cls, inst: inst in ('both', 'advertise'))
    both = 'both'
    advertise = 'advertise'
```

This code works fine with Python 2 but doesn't compile with Python 3 and to resolve it I need to change it to

```
class Sample(object):
    __slots__ = ('both', 'advertise')
    class __metaclass__(type):
        __instancecheck__ = classmethod(
                lambda cls, inst: inst in ('both', 'advertise'))
    def __init__(self):
        both = 'both'
        advertise = 'advertise'
```

**What would be an efficient way to handle this change given that it has to be done over such a large file multiple times?**

We have to consider that there may or may not be a `__init__` function definition already for the class and there can be nested class definitions as well.

This is what I have tried so far.

- `2to3` doesn't recognize this as an issue and hence doesn't change it.
- One possible way could be to use `ast` module to modify the parse tree in memory and then use `unparse` to write back the modified code. But it is not straightforward.
- If nothing else works, I will consider writing a simple Shell/Python script which will read the source file, make changes and write it back.

Can there be another quick and simple way to handle this change.

Comment: [Metaclasses have changed in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), `__metaclass__` doesn't work anymore. You could also replace the metaclasses (one for each class here) with one common metaclass and use `lambda cls, inst: inst in cls.__slots__)` which should work for all classes.

Comment: And you could also replace the code in `__init__` with `for slot in __slots__: setattr(self, slot, slot)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any better way than to write a small script. I think the changes are small enough that you can get away with some nice heuristics and don't need the full power of `ast`.

However, if you have this much repetition of code, I would remove the classes from your code altogether. You can replace them with either a code generator or write a factory function for these classes. This is going to future-proof your code for any changes.

Such a factory could look like this:

```
class HasStringInstances(type):
    def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
        return instance in cls.__slots__

def create_special_class(*slots):
    class SpecialClass(object, metaclass=HasStringInstances):
        __slots__ = slots

        def __init__(self):
            for slot in self.__slots__:
                 # assign name as value
                 setattr(self, slot, slot)

    return SpecialClass

Sample = create_special_class('both', 'advertise')
```

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a good feedback. Yes, `ast` seemed too heavyweight for this. Moreover , nodes in the `ast.NodeVisitor` class doesn't have pointer / link to parent, so it seemed difficult to move nodes in the parse tree.